# Restrict reading access to a user for everything outside of a directory

Tags: permissions, user-permissions

I have set a users permission like this

```
groupadd mygroup
useradd -G mygroup ftp
chown -R :mygroup /var/www
chmod -R g+rw /var/www
```

Now how can I restrict access for this user (or is it group?) to allow the user to not be able to read anything out of the directory `/var/www`?

Comment: Is the user going to be allowed shell access, or only FTP? Because the second is much easier to ensure than the first.

Comment: The user is going to be only allowed ftp!

Comment: Then please choose a [FTP server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_software) and read it's manual. The relevant term is typically how to set up "chroot" users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to edit `/etc/vsftpd.conf` to read:

```
chroot_local_user=YES
```

And then perform the command:

```
usermod --home /var/www/ ftp
```

Where `ftp` is the user